Being full of manners x Being well behaved
In a short YouTube video, a little boy alongside his father is amazed by the beauty of a car parked on the street. The owner of the car appears and opens the car for the boy to admire its interior and even allows the boy to get inside the car. The boy, even more amazed, respectfully declines the offer. In the comments, someone says:
He didn't even touch it. A boy full of manners.
And then someone responds:
It's not manners it's called being well behaved.
And then someone responds to this previous comment:
In this case, it's pretty much exactly the definition of having good manners. Respectfully asking someone before touching they're (theirs?) things. Mannerly.
As far as I can understand, the meaning of a person (or, in this case, a boy) being "full of manners" or "having good manners" would be similar or even identical to "being well behaved", but in the dialogue above, it seems that these are treated as different qualities. As if in the second comment the guy was saying something like "you're wrong, he's not a boy full of manners, he is actually a well behaved boy.
Am I getting it all wrong here or do both expressions really have different meanings?
Here's the video I'm talking about: www.youtube.com/shorts/s-7H7rjymB4

A boy full of manners isn't remotely idiomatic to me. Either a non-native Anglophone, or a deliberately quirky usage (akin to He's made of manners or He could manner for England!).

...His grin is made of politeness. Deliberately "weird".

The third speaker says that [being well-behaved] is exactly the definition of 'having good manners' - which is true. The only difference I can think of is that 'well-behaved' is more often used of children.

full of manners, good or bad, is really not idiomatic at all. Very well mannered we say. Or x has good manners. Full of manners sounds like bad translation.

First: "full of manners" is not a standard idiomatic usage, so I wouldn't worry too much about it. I'm not sure where the video was shot, but along with English, I hear Italian, and I think Russian? Those writing comments might also be English learners, and nonstandard usages shouldn't be surprising. "Having good manners" and "mannerly" are more standard, so we can focus on those.
One person, at least, seems to make a distinction between "manners" and "being well-behaved." I'm not sure it makes sense to insist on this distinction strongly, but there's something to it. "Manners" often means "etiquette," a social code of conduct. Etiquette is sometimes criticized as arbitrary or useless, a set of rituals that enforce social boundaries without having any practical benefit: who cares which fork you use for the salad? This commenter seems to be setting "behavior" against arbitrary rules. Perhaps this commenter would say that there's no specific rule of etiquette that would have forbidden the boy from even touching the car; they see it simply as "being good."
These criticisms of etiquette are sometimes countered by pointing out that the heart and soul of etiquette is simply kindness and consideration. Behind the "arbitrary" rules we can find thoughtfulness for others. "Don't chew with your mouth open" ... because it grosses other people out. "Say sir, ma'am, please, and thank you"... because you honor others and value their kindness. This seems to be the viewpoint from which the next commenter responds: being "well behaved," being respectful and considerate, is to them "exactly the definition of having good manners" rather than a separate concept.
If you're concerned about how to use these phrases more broadly, you might say "Your boy is so well behaved" if the boy is playing by himself quietly, ignoring the grown-ups—he isn't doing anything naughty—and "your boy has such good manners" if he greets you with a title of respect, holds a door for you, or otherwise observes some of the social rituals that we value. But don't worry too much about swapping them, since they overlap so much.

Not standard English usage? It ain't English at all. Why not just call it?

@Lambie Meh, just in case it has some niche regional usage that I'm not aware of. We don't cover such, just mainstream AmE and BrE, but I was stopping short of saying "nobody says it anywhere" just because I don't know all usages. But more likely it's just direct translation from the idiomatic pattern of some other language.

See my comment under the question.
